# for, foreach and other loops in github-actions

Tags: github-actions

There is a "if" available in github-actions.

Is there any way to do use loops? (for, foreach, while , ...)

something like

```
- foreach val in ['val1', 'val2']
```

Comment: Nope, that is not possible and there are no signs that they will add this, even if is a very popular request.

Answer (score 11):

In one word - no. But there is a [matrix](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs) mechanism that probably will help you. Share more details about the problem you want to solve using loops.

Comment: the matrix strategy will create a different job for every valid combination of the parameters. This might not be what one wants (even with parallelism=1), as it's different from looping a step over a list of value within the same job.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe not what you are looking for, but you can use a run in the action

```
  - name: Print things
    run: |
      for x in ${{ y }}; do
        echo "$x"
      done
```

Answer (score 1):

Looping is not currently possible, especially if you consider looping by using the same runner.

Matrix can be used to run a variable number of jobs, but that adds a considerable complexity and huge increase in resource usage, so directly slower results.